# Error : SavedStateRegistry was already restored

Tags: android, kotlin

Sorry cannot post the source code due to data privacy. Why(what can be the reason) does following type of crash occur. In my case its happening when I come back to the app from tapping on notification.
Logs are as follows:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SavedStateRegistry was already restored.
    at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.performRestore$savedstate_release(SavedStateRegistry.kt:221) 
at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryController.performRestore(SavedStateRegistryController.kt:69) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.performRestore(FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:170) at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:693)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:3151)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:3142)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:579)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:264)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2895)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:3143)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:579)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:264)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1817)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1729)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:317)
```

Tried to debug app but nothing useful found. Tried commenting code from onResume activity but its not causing the this crash.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue using Capacitor. I had to comment the line `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in the file `android/app/src/main/java/[APP_DOMAIN_NAME]/MainActivity.java`

Result of this file:

```
package [MY APP];

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // comment the below line
    // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    registerPlugin(HttpClientPlugin.class);
    registerPlugin(SystemLogPlugin.class);
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```